# Calculating an average with an array in Java; Homework

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment, and these are the 5 questions,

> 1. What is the total of all the elements in the array.
> 2. What is the average of all the elements in the array.
> 3. What are the largest and smallest numbers in the array. (one loop for both questions)
> 4. Display all the odd numbers in the array. Use the modulus function (%) on page 46.
> 5. Print every other number in the array.

I am having trouble finding the average, or writing the code that finds it.

```
public class JavaApplication {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int nums[] = {33,66,77,88,60,91,87,92,76,90};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            sum +=nums[i];

        }    
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);

        int average = 0;                         Here
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {  |
            sum = sum + nums[i];                 |
        }
        System.out.println("Average value is " + average); and here.


        int min, max;                                        
        min = max = nums [0];
        for(int i=1; i < 10; i++) {
            if(nums[i] < min) min = nums[i];
            if(nums[i] > max) max = nums[i];
        }
        System.out.println("min and max: " + min + " " + max);


    }
}
```

This is my second week in this class, So please explain what needs to be added or not and thanks :)

Comment: what have you tried?  are you familiar with what the formula is to average n elements ?

Comment: Remember:  average = sum / length of collection.  Be sure that your sum is a double or you will have floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: You already have sum and number of elements. Try to combine them (also remember that `int/int` returns `int`, if you want to return double at least one of operands also needs to be of double type)

Comment: I have tryed defining the variable average, as well as using double, but i would get the error already defined variable in the main string. 

my understanding it has to be all in one format, like i already used int sum = 0; to find the total, how  can i use that again for the average?

Comment: @Pshemo can you elaborate on your comment? not sure what that means, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The pseudo code to average n elements :

```
1) Add up all of the element values
2) Divide the result from step 1 by the number of elements in your collection
```

Comment: I have added all the elements, that is what the int sum = 0 part is for right?

Comment: @Pshemo like i said i am very new, and half the stuff i used google for help, my book doesnt say how to calculate the average or the code for it. and my teacher just gave us these questions for our first assignment.

Comment: yes so there is one more step, to divide by the number of elements in the array.  Have you figured out how to do that?

Comment: I have not, i would guess thats what the (nums.length / sum is for correct?  Not sure.

Comment: and where would that go? again sorry still new, thanks for the help

int average = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
           sum = sum + nums[i];    
       }
    System.out.println("Average value is " + (sum / nums.length));

Comment: average = sum / nums.lenth

Comment: if i put it like this it wont display anything, not sure what im missing or doing wrong.
int average = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
           average = sum / nums.length;    
       }
    System.out.println("Average value is " + (sum / nums.length));